# how to change ExpandableListview left icon to others (android ExpandableListView)

Tags: android

Now I want to use a ExpandableListView to display my data and I want to change the item left icon  or  let it disappear. can some one give me a suggestion .

thx.

Answer (score 4):

`setGroupIndicator(null)` should make it go away.

Answer (score 1):

In this video, you can find preciesly how you can change the icons (in expandable list).

[39 Android Tutorial Working with ExpandableListView 6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asjJTn8ro38)

Answer (score 0):

Other option to remove the default icon from the .xml layout.

```
<ExpandableListView 
   ... 
   ...
    android:groupIndicator="@null" />
```

or

```
 getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(null);
```